# Could not find version error 141 Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

getting:
 Error: Could not find version 2014-07-03T19:23:23.522Z for main.js (Code: 141, Version: 1.2.19)

often, and then it goes away. It looks like parse is having issues... was wondering if anyone knew what the deal is with this error, and when will parse become stable...

They closed their forum on their site, so I couldn't post this there... which is not a good sign... hope they are not going out of business or falling apart. We have based our entire product on them. A comment from a parser would be appreciated.

Comment: Please click the Bug Tool button under Report a Bug here:  https://parse.com/help  FYI Parse was acquired by Facebook in May 2013 and has gotten much much larger since then.

Comment: The bug is open here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1503445339870105

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a temporary server issue, not a programming issue.

Comment: Just ran into this issue as well when trying to `parse deploy`. Clearly not resolved...!  What is the workaround in the mean time?